# Redirect secured domain to secured subdomain using htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, ssl, subdomain

I have 3 domains and one hosting. I am trying to use the same hosting for all of my three domains through htaccess. So, I created a subdomains with that name on my domain linked with hosting, which looks something like below.

`www.site1.com` [Main domain linked with hosting]

`site2.site1.com` [subdomain for `www.site2.com`]

`site3.site1.com` [subdomain for `www.site3.com`]

What I want to achieve is, user shouldn't go to subdomain `site2.site1.com`, instead they would be able to go to `www.site2.com` only and request will be sent to `site2.site1.com` at backend.

Up to here, all is done and worked well. The only problem comes afterwards, when I adds `SSL` on site. I have `SSL` for all of these domain and subdomain. If a user visit non-ssl, then he should be redirected to SSL one. Some of SSL works well but when I add SSL for all of them, then I start getting `500` error.

Here is my `.htaccess` file

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site2.site1.com/$1 [P]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site2.site1.com/$1 [P]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site3.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site3.site1.com/$1 [P]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site3.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://site3.site1.com/$1 [P]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

As I add `https` on redirection link, so it start giving me `500` error whereas when I make redirection to `http` then it will not load my page because non-secured site `http://site2.site1.com` will be loaded over secured `https://www.site2.com` and in a result, nothing will be shown.

Here I need help to resolve this problem. I have looked over different questions but haven't found any question relevant to me because I need to keep my `.htaccess` working with redirection and `SSL`. Moreover, I also need to redirect to `www` one, if not added in URL.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like, all the times I experienced here I have resolved my problem myself. The resolution to my problem was the following `htaccess`

```
RewriteEngine On
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) site2/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site2.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) site2/$1

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^site3.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) site3/$1
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.site3.com
RewriteRule ^(.*) site3/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

In this way instead of pointing the URL to `subdomain` having `https` I have reference that to the directory instead because path will be same for that, and now when I enter the `URL` with `https` page opens and don't give any error.